# float numerical operations using a function template

Tags: c++, gcc, types, casting, clang

I have the following function:

```
template <typename T>
T foo (T x, T y){
    double sum = 0;
    sum = static_cast<double>(x) + static_cast<double>(y);
    return sum;
    }
```

this function should receive any 2 numbers of the same type compute their sum and return it as the same type, but when called for example using

```
foo<char>(1.5, 1.5)
```

it returns `2` and not `3`

Comment: This is the exact dupe of: [cast the output of a template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74039020/cast-the-output-of-a-template-function). Kindly don't ask the exact same questions after deleting the old one when they get closed. Instead improve on the question.

Answer (score 0):

`char` represents integral numbers, therefore `1.5` is truncated to `1` and `1 + 1 == 2`.

Based on the fact that you cast arguments to double, it's likely better to take double as well:

```
template <typename T>
T foo (double x, double y){
    return static_cast<T>(x + y); // static_cast to disable warnings
}
```

Also, it's worth to implement bounds checking, otherwise your code can contain UB.